# SpringBoot 401 UnAuthorized even with out security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, controller

I did not use Spring Security but it is asking me to authenticate.

[image]

Exception for URL(http://localhost:8080/SpringJob/ExecuteJob):

```
{
    "timestamp": 1500622875056,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Bad credentials",
    "path": "/SPPA/ExecuteSPPAJob"
}
----below log details
2017-07-21 13:15:35.210  INFO 19828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/SpringJob]   : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-07-21 13:15:35.210 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO 
                    o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/SpringJob]-Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 
2017-07-21 13:15:35.211  INFO 19828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-07-21 13:15:35.211 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO 
                    o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started 
2017-07-21 13:15:35.494  INFO 19828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 282 ms
2017-07-21 13:15:35.494 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO 
                    o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 282 ms
```

application-dev.xml

```
#Spring Boot based configurations
management.security.enabled: "false"
spring.autoconfigure.exclude:  "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration"
spring.batch.job.enabled: false
server.contextPath: /SpringJob
```

build.gradle snippet

```
plugins {
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.5'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: "no.nils.wsdl2java"
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
    //compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws', version: '3.1.10'
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-ws-security', version: '3.1.10'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @RequestMapping("/ExecuteJob")
    @ResponseBody
    public String callPrelegalJob(@RequestParam("user") String userName, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
        log.info("Job is to be launched from controller...");
}
}
```

Comment: This is because of cxf-rt-ws-security

Comment: How to overcome this, thanks for reply

Comment: either you can comment out the dependency if the security thing is not your first priority..else you need to customize the configuration to set the Authentication details

Comment: check this http://techtots.blogspot.in/2016/07/enabling-ws-security-in-spring-boot.html

Comment: Is there any way to disable this authentication in application.properties ? because czf-rt-ws-security is used only for SOAP service call from Spring not for authentication.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try to add below lines in your `application.properties` file

```
security.basic.enable: false
security.ignored=/**
```

According to spring doc, use `security.ignored=`

> Comma-separated list of paths to exclude from the default secured
>   paths

Comment: This works @Afridi thanks, please provide me doc link if you can.

Comment: @sunleo navigate to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html and then search for the word "security.ignored="

Comment: This doesn't currently work, and the link above does not contain "security.ignored" on it

Comment: @trevorsky This option was available till 1.5.8.RELEASE release, and above link is referencing to current release which is currently 2.1.x. May be they removed it now. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.8.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: @alfridi Thanks, yeah it looks like a lot changed in this area from 2+. We ended up adding an explicit piece of code to disable security, as a temporary fix until we prioritize learning and adding a proper security configuration. I'll add it as an answer below for others like me who stumble into this thread.

Comment: These have been deprecated

Comment: security.basic.enabled: false --> enabled not enable

Answer (score 55):

In the current version of Spring Boot (v2.1.0.RELEASE), the easiest way to get rid of the security issues is to add "WebSecurityConfig.java" to your project as follows:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

Note of course that this removes protection against cross-site request forgery, so this is really only appropriate for simple read-only endpoints.

Answer (score 18):

Just remove the the spring security dependency from pom.xml file.
Worked for me :)..

Comment: remove this: `compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')` if it is present by any chance

Comment: another way of doing same thing by adding exclusion on main class
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64132119/6589216

Answer (score 14):

if we use CXF security & Spring boot security it gives this issues.
Comment out dependency i.e disable the spring boot security then it allows.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>       
</dependency>
```

To enable this we have to write custom security or add below config

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked with Spring boot 2.2.6.RELEASE, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Exact way to disable authentication could not be found by me.But by removing actuator dependency which is working.

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
```

Answer (score 5):

@harshit-sharma 's solution worked for me; I added exclusion in my main Application class:

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the springSecurityFilterChain to ignore all requests and thus allow unauthenticated access to all your endpoints with the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer

Comment: Also what package is WebSecurity in. I would actually like to open up a single point but I can't import WebSecurity

Comment: @JGleason WebSecurity is in spring-security-config from spring-security.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security may still be in the project libs via transitive dependencies. What should still work in Spring Boot is the following:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .permitAll();
    }
```

Note: the http is a `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity` and this is in a `@Component` that may already be injected into and called by some `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` [implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html) in your application's framework. This should override any built-in catch-all clause, i.e. `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().denyAll()` for testing purposes etc..

Answer (score 0):

Adding this configuration bean solved the problem for me:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: it will throw compilation exception as spring boot security dependency is not there?

Comment: Yes, use it only if you have spring boot security on your class path.

Answer (score -1):

I solved by removed this dependency from `pom.xml`

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```