# How to debug unauthorized 401 errors in springboot even without security

Tags: spring-boot

I have a simple web application in which my path to `/` gives the error

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-10-11T11:51:18.961+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/"
}
```

on hitting the path I do not get logs as well
I checked [this question in stackoverflow as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45232071/springboot-401-unauthorized-even-with-out-security)

Comment: Add your POM, any relevant configuration, properties etc.

Comment: The issue seems to have gotten fixed when I tried with this tutorial (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration).
I was using Spring-Boot-2. Will need to update myself on the framework more